# Scala console doesn't display the elements generated in range sequence

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, range

I am learning Scala language and using Intellij editor. I was exploring the range sequence in Scala console. With the below code, it generates a range sequence, but it is not displaying the elements. I tried this in Eclipse as well, but didn't get the elements. Is there any option available to make the elements of the range sequence to be displayed?

I tried to generate a range sequence from 1 to 10

```
scala> 1 to 10
res15: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range 1 to 10

scala> res15
res16: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range 1 to 10
```

I expected the elements in the range sequence to be displayed.

Comment: you need to use print or println if you want to display it to console

Comment: No, it doesn't work.  ``` scala> println(res16)
Range 1 to 10 ```

Comment: This is what i mean (1 to 10).foreach(println)

Comment: Thanks. It worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ranges in Scala are not like arrays or lists in other languages - their elements are not all stored in memory. Instead, they are abstract sequences that are defined by 3 values - their start, their end, and the stepping value: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/concrete-immutable-collection-classes.html#ranges

If you want to see your values, you can convert your range to a list:

```
scala> (1 to 10).toList
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```